# Backpropogation: WHERE is Derivative of Transfer Function

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, derivative

First off: I understand derivatives and the chain rule. I'm not great with math, but I have an understanding.

Numerous tutorials on Backpropogation (let's use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropogation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule)) using gradient descent state that we use the derivative of the transfer function (sigmoid or tanh) to calculate the gradient and hence which way to travel next.  In these tutorials I see (t-o)(1-o)(o) as the formula for calculating the error for the output neurons, which seems to be the derivative of the error calculation (1/2)(t-o)^2 * (1-o).  (t = target, o = output_actual)

Why do I not see the derivative of the transfer function (assuming sigmoid): e^x/((e^x + 1)^2)  anywhere?  Or for when tanh is used as the transfer function: sech^2(x)  ... where 
x = weighted input?

Also, some tutorials use (target - actual) ,  (target - actual)^2 [ Sum of Squares - useful for negative outputs]  or the squared error function: (1/2)(target - actual)^2.

Where is the derivative of the transfer function and which is the correct error formula to use?

Comment: Have you looked for 'Quasi-Newton' method ?

Comment: No, but I will.  I am more concerned at understanding the most common (and easiest to find examples of) method of the error propogation before I begin modifying it further.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this could been an explanation why you can't find the derivative of the TF because pseudo-newton method don't need it

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I not see the derivative of the transfer function (assuming sigmoid): e^x/((e^x + 1)^2) anywhere?

You do, its expressed as [image] with the derivative [image] in the wiki page you link. If we expand the latter we get

(1/(1+e^-x))*(1-1/(1+e^-x)) = e^x/(e^x+1)^2

which is the original form you noted.

> Or for when tanh is used as the transfer function: sech^2(x) ... where x = weighted input?

Well, in this case its because the page doesn't mention the tanh as a potential activation function. But in real life it is expressed in a similar way so that we can avoid any unnecessary computations.

> (target - actual)^2 [ Sum of Squares - useful for negative outputs] or the squared error function: (1/2)(target - actual)^2.

The difference is only a constant factor. The math comes out a little nicer if you keep the division by 2. In practice the only thing that would change is your learning rate gets implicitly multiplied/divided by 2 depending on which perspective you look at.

> Also, some tutorials use (target - actual)

You probably misread. (t-a) would be the derivative of (t-a)^2/2 . Just (t-a) would have a derivative of -1, which I'm fairly sure would hinder learning for a nn.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common calculus topic to find derivatives for functions.

You may also use online mathematica to do so, here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

The code to enter is

```
D[ 1/(1+e^(-x)), x ]
```

You can enter any function using Mathematica notation: http://integrals.wolfram.com/about/input/.

With the derivative, you can plug it in the general formula for error functions. When the derivative is too complex, you can try to use the function Simplify[...] to find better analytic forms.

As for choosing which transfer function to use, you can consider their domains and ranges. The logistic function (1 / (1 + exp(-x)) has range (0,1) but the atan(x) function has range (-1, 1). If you perform mathematical analysis on the learning algorithms, the choice of the transfer function may matter a lot. However, if you are running simulations, the choice of transfer functions should not be critical, as long as they have the S-shape (sigmoidal).

Another thing to pint out, the logistic function (1 / (1 + exp(-x) ) is only one instance of sigmoidal functions. atan(x) is also sigmoidal.

Comment: You clearly did not read my question. e^x/((e^x + 1)^2) is the derivative of the sigmoid function.

Comment: OK. It's corrected. The formula for the logistic function is 1/(1+e^(-x)). Please distinguish logistic function and sigmoidal functions, which is often confused. atan is also sigmoidal.